# c# using the event handler WorkbookOpen

Tags: c#, excel, event-handling, add-in

I am programming an excel add-in and I want to execute certain code when a workbook is opened.  This means that if they open excel and then open a workbook, the add-in will execute the code.

I am assuming we have to use the event handler:
Application.WokbookOpen

But I do not know how to apply this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to `InternalStartUp()`

```
    this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
```

And then this function will be called when the workbook is opened

```
void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
   //Do something         
}
```

Also, it is hidden in the `#region VSTO generated code` in `ThisAddIn.cs` by default.