# c# excel addin workbook close event

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

i make an Excel COM Add-In.
Now i want to Control the WorkbookBeforeClose Event.
But the Solution that i found on Stackoverflow ([c# using the event handler WorkbookOpen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180318/c-sharp-using-the-event-handler-workbookopen)) works not for me.
In my Add-In there is no InternalStartup Sektion, there is only a Load Sektion.
I can only Start the Eventhandler by pushing a Button in my Ribbon Bar.
When i push the Button 1x the Eventhandler do what i want all the Time Excel is loaded.
When Excel is closed and restart i must Push the Button again.
Is there a Way that the Eventhandler ist Starting while Excel loads the first empty Workbook ???
Is there some Help or any Solution for me ???

Thanks and Regards
Stephan

Here is my Code, that i use for the EventHandler:

```
public partial class Excel2SE  
{  
   Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler EventDel_BeforeBookClose;

private void Excel2SE_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
   EventDel_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(BeforeBookClose);
}

private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   wbEventhandlerStart();
}

private void wbEventhandlerStart()
{
   Excel.Application app = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
   app.WorkbookBeforeClose += EventDel_BeforeBookClose;
} 

// This Works when Excel Close
private void Excel2SE_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Excel close");
} 

// This works after Pushing the Start Button and the Workbook Close
private void BeforeBookClose(Excel.Workbook Wb, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show("WB close");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Visual Studio Office Add-In? It sounds like it is, if so check ThisAddIn.cs for the following 2 methods:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

You can add the code you want to run on close to the **ThisAddIn_Shutdown** method. There's no way to ensure this code runs however, it will only run if the user closes Excel 'properly'. If they close using the task manager etc, all bets are off.