# Handling Events that cannot be accessed from the ribbon visual designer

Tags: excel, vsto

How does one go about handling events that cannot be accessed from the ribbon visual designer in visual studio?

For example I would like to handle a mouse movement into the activesheet or if a user switches between worksheets. How do I go about subscribing to that event? Is there any way to generate an event handler for these kinds of events (that don't involve controls in the ribbon) automatically in visual studio.

Ive spent quite a few hours trying to figure this out (I am new to VSTO and c#) with no luck.

Thanks a lot

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7180318](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180318/c-sharp-using-the-event-handler-workbookopen)

Answer (score 0):

Many excel objects expose events. Look into Worksheet and Workbook events for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet_events.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_events.aspx